# What is `pc=` parameter in EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error?

Tags: java, jvm

Java running failed with the following errors (several times):

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe618b69d3, pid=16724, tid=35304
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa8b763ea6, pid=11972, tid=28788
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa8b6e1dc1, pid=18692, tid=27188
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000023de8f29210, pid=20428, tid=8244
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa8b6e72fc, pid=27652, tid=26904
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe61413beb, pid=33888, tid=20428
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa99a8143d, pid=3512, tid=28808
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa8b699648, pid=3688, tid=25668
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffdf5c433ce, pid=3696, tid=29448
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffdf5a3ba99, pid=376, tid=31532
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000001f9a29f85e0, pid=8596, tid=29104
```

What is `pc` is it memory address? Is there a way to determine memory address?

Comment: pc == program counter

Comment: ok and what is the value? Can it be "translated" to memory address?

Comment: I would say that pc = program counter, pid = process ID and tid = thread ID. Program counter is the memory place where binary code is located. I don't post it as an answer yet because I didn't found any official confirmation, and I don't know if that memory location would contains Java bytecode or native assemblee. Does anyone has official details ?

Comment: This is not a Java problem. You are probably using LWJGL. _some errors in user programs can cause the JVM to crash without a meaningful error message, since LWJGL 3 is tuned for extreme speed at the expense of robustness._ Try to start your program with [LWJGLX/debug](https://github.com/LWJGLX/debug)

Answer (score 2):

pc means "program counter", what follows (for example 0x00007ffe618b69d3) is the memory address of the instruction that caused the access violation.

The code is not loaded at fixed addresses and therefore with the current information it's impossible to say what caused the access violation and which code is responsible.

---

Hints for further investigation (and the reason why I don't write just a comment):

- the information that you show is normally written into a "hs_err_pidxxxx" file where xxxx matches the value from "pid=xxxx"
- a few lines after the lines that you have included are normally lines like

> ```
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  [msvcr100.dll+0x121f4]
> ```

These lines give some more information: in the case that I had for reference, the access violation occurred within the "msvcr100.dll" at code offset 0x121f4. And the letter `C` indicates that in this case the exception occurred in native code.

- a few more lines down there is usually a block starting with "----  T H R E A D  ----". This block usually contains much more information (values of the processor registers, excerpt from the stack, excerpt from the running code, a stacktrace that better identifies what was executing when the exception happened).

Without more details from these sources it is hard to tell what caused the access violation exception (except maybe the most probably it was something in native code - in Java code the JVM catches most of these exceptions and converts them into Java Exceptions).